# How to change GitHub accounts when trying to push from Git?

Tags: java, git, github, push

So I may have set up Git under an account that I will not be using in the future, and I want to change that account to my personal GitHub account. I would like to push under my personal rather than that one.

If this has any relevance, I've created a separate SSH key for my computer, but as inexperienced as I am, I'm not sure what to do with it.

My ultimate goal is to change the GitHub account I'm under, because whenever I try to push code to my personal account's repository, I get this error message:

```
$ git push origin master
remote: Permission to maiusername/SURVIVAL2.git denied to SupernovaRobotics.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/maiusername/SURVIVAL2.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

SupernovaRobotics is what I'm trying to get rid of, but I'm not sure how!

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Add your public ssh key to your GitHub account (drop down on the top right, settings, SSH and GPG keys, new SSH key).
Then execute:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/desiredrepo.git
```

This command changes the repository of origin.1

Comment: I did that, I added the key to "...Robotics" and performed the above code (it didn't return anything) but as I entered "git push origin master" it returned the same error. I've also tried searching for the SSH key by git bash but it always returned "no such file or directory" so I found the key info in Git GUI. I wonder if that could be of any help?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are pushing to an *https* url, changing anything regarding *SSH* won't matter one bit.

Regarding HTTPS, if the wrong user is consistently used, that means the wrong credentials (username/password) is used by Git. That is because you must be using a **[credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials)** which caches said credentials.

Check what credential helper you are using with:

```
git config -l | grep credential
```

---

The alternative (if you do have changed your ~/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub) keys) is to use an ssh url

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:maiusername/SURVIVAL2.git
```

*Then* your new ssh key would be taken into account.

Answer (score -1):

U need:

- to access your windows credential manager;
- clik in "windows's credentical" (I don't know how u will to see this because my windowns is in portuguese)
- look for "git:https://..." and remove this
  So, when u to try push again, git will to ask u to connect with you github account and u connect in your new acconut :)

Comment: Please click the [edit] button and replace every occurence of "u" with the proper "you". Thanks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).